# How can I view a test ARB transaction in authorize.net?

Tags: php, authorize.net

I just set up an ARB page for my sandbox authorize.net account and I am fairly certain the transaction is going through, as my error_log has nothing in it, but I wanted to view the dummy info that I sent to make sure it's actually logging this transaction somehow if that is even possible. I'm just using the sample data from that test subscription page and sending it out. Am I able to view that my authorize.net sandbox account received this data anywhere?

I have tried this in both live/test modes and subscriptions remain at 0 for both modes.

If I cannot test it this way, how can I get the page that's sending the request to report back to me that the request/response was successful?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php/blob/master/README.md shows examples how to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to login in authorize.net merchant account and then set a silent post url there and when ever a transaction will be done then it will return response in json format and you need to capture that event in your silent post url script and that response need to store in a table field and later on you can check about it.

for further assistance you can check following url.

http://www.johnconde.net/blog/tutorial-integrate-the-authorize-net-arb-api-with-php/